# Security of data transmission between Android wear and smartphone

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have an application for Android wear. I use GoogleApiClient to send message between Android wear and smartphone.

Is this communication safe? Is it safe to send sensitive data between devices, like password? Maybe I have to protect the data in some way?

Send message looks like this:

```
Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleApiClient, nodeId, path, message.getBytes()).await();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi.html):

> A message is private to the application that created it and accessible only by that application on other nodes.

Although the underlying Bluetooth connection is encrypted it is considered to be [breakable](http://www.wareable.com/android-wear/android-wear-hack-alert-signalled-by-security-expert-581). However, I'm not aware of detailed information if and how exactly the communication is secured on a higher level.