# Does Android Wear communicate securely with paired smartphones over the Internet?

Tags: android, wear-os

It's great that Android Wear devices will be able to communicate with their devices over wi-fi (with the phone being online with cellular data, the same wi-fi network or a different wi-fi network), but is this secure? Bluetooth should be reasonably safe, and the phone app can make sure to use HTTPS to communicate sensitive data back and forth with a web server--but how exposed or secure is that data when the phone sends it to the Android Wear device?

I'm unable to find any solid information on this from Google.

Similar questions:
[Security of data transmission between Android wear and smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754925/security-of-data-transmission-between-android-wear-and-smartphone) mainly asks about protecting data from other apps on the phone.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937830/how-can-i-establish-the-level-of-security-provided-by-the-channel-between-androi is about bluetooth communication.